# Select component instance by directive via @ViewChildren in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have multiple components, such as `FirstTabComponent`, `SecondTabComponent`, etc...

In the parent component I need to be able to select all component instances.

I tried to use a common directive as a selector, but it only allows me to select either a Directive Instance or a Component Instance...

```js
@Directive({selector: '[tab]'})
export class Tab {}

export interface Tab {
    goNext(): Observable<any>;
}

@Component({...})
export class FirstTabComponent implements Tab {}

@Component({...})
export class SecondTabComponent implements Tab {}

// Wrapper Component Template
<app-first-component tab></app-first-component>
<app-second-component tab></app-second-component>

// Wrapper Component

// This approach selects only 1 component
@ViewChildren(Tab, {read: FirstTabComponent}) tabs: QueryList<Tab>;

// Whereas this one selects directive
@ViewChildren(Tab,) tabs: QueryList<Tab>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use a template tag as your selector:

```
<app-first-component #tab></app-first-component>
<app-second-component #tab></app-second-component>
```

and then select it like

```
@ViewChildren('tab') tabs: QueryList<Tab>;
```

Comment: Brilliant. Cheers pal.